# Problem with plugins during NopCommerce development

Tags: c#, .net-core, nopcommerce

I'm going to do some development on NopCommerce 4.0.
I have imported NopCommerce 4.0 source codes into VS 2019. When I try to run my project, all of plugins generate exceptions like this inside `Resolve` method `NopEngine.cs`:

```
public object Resolve(Type type)
{
    return GetServiceProvider().GetRequiredService(type);
}
```

E.g. one of the exceptions is:

> 'Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder.CheckMoneyOrderPaymentProcessor'
>   has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a
>   component to provide the service, check for service registration using
>   IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an
>   optional dependency.

And here is complete exception details:

> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException
>   HResult=0x80131500   Message=The requested service
>   'Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder.CheckMoneyOrderPaymentProcessor'
>   has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a
>   component to provide the service, check for service registration using
>   IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an
>   optional dependency.   Source=Autofac   StackTrace:    at
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context,
>   Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(Type
>   serviceType)    at Nop.Core.Infrastructure.NopEngine.Resolve(Type
>   type) in
>   V:\nopCommerce_4.00_Source\Libraries\Nop.Core\Infrastructure\NopEngine.cs:line
>   254

Answer (score 2):

That seems issues with nop v4.0 as it was loading uninstalled plugins in memory, and has been resolved in v4.10. Either you can upgrade to the updated version or check following fix, if it would work!

Change

```
public object Resolve(Type type)
{
    return GetServiceProvider().GetRequiredService(type);
}
```

To

```
public object Resolve(Type type)
{
    if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BasePlugin))) {
        return null;
    }
    return GetServiceProvider().GetRequiredService(type);
}
```

Comment: The problem is I have this plugins, but I don't know why they cannot be loaded correctly to avoid exceptions. May be I did not include them correctly in my project but I don't know what is the right way to do this. Do you know?

Comment: @VSB: If you are running with default plugins provided with the source code, then this seem more like issue with code or approach that they are using. If this issue with other plugins then that might be possible cause how you added those.

Comment: This problem exist with default plugins and external plugins which compiled already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error when I forgot to register service with it interface

Eg :

```
public class DependencyRegistrar : IDependencyRegistrar
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Register services and interfaces
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="builder">Container builder</param>
   /// <param name="typeFinder">Type finder</param>
   /// <param name="config">Config</param>
   public virtual void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, ITypeFinder typeFinder, NopConfig config)
   {
      //register service manager
      builder.RegisterType<SearchFilterService>().As<ISearchFilterService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
      builder.RegisterType<ElasticSearchService>().As<IElasticSearchService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();          
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Gets order of this dependency registrar implementation
   /// </summary>
   public int Order => 1;
}
```